# Javascript increasing percentage on input

Tags: javascript

This is my edit so far .. but if i run it like this, it gives me an error because it never ends.

I think i added most of the notes you have suggested, but It is still not coming out right.

Correction, I get the prompts to appear, but after i enteer in a price and a day number, nothing happens.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt() {
    var original = prompt("Original Price","Enter Number Here");
    var day = prompt("Day of the Sale","1 - 4");
        do{
            if (day == "1"){
            newprice1 = (original * 0.1)
            document.write('Total : '+newprice1);
            }
            else if (day == "2"){
            newprice2 = (newprice1 * 0.1)
            document.write('Total : '+newprice2);
            }
            else if (day == "3"){
            newprice3 = (newprice2 * 0.1)
            document.write('Total : '+newprice3);
            }
            else if (day == "4"){
            newprice4 = (newprice3 * 0.1)
            document.write('Total : '+newprice4);
            }

        }
            while (day <= "4"){
    }
}
show_prompt();
document.write('Original Price : '+original);
document.write('<br>Day of Sale : '+day);
</script>
```

Comment: along with @Brennan's answer, `if (day = 1)` will assign 1 to day, not test it for equality

Comment: Is it me, or shouldn't the comparison operators be `==` : `if (day == 1) { ... }`.

Comment: It never ends because `day` never changes (within the `do { } while` loop).

Comment: how do i get the "day" to change ?

Comment: You could omit the loop (not sure what it's doing for you), or convert `day` to a number and increment it (`++day <= 4`) in the `while` statement.

Comment: @IanA: Assign something to it? You really should study your Javascript book. This question is far too basic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

you closed do's bracket after the while.

the correct syntax is do { ... } while ( ... )

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons will always return false because the input coming from the user will be a string, which you are comparing to a number. Either parse the input as an int, or compare against strings:

```
if (parseInt(day,10) == 1)
```

or

```
if (day == "1")
```

Comment: Neither of these is a comparison, they're both assignments.

Comment: Whoops, I copy-pasted without paying attention